# Return month and date only once using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, date

I am creating a archive of posts which I want to create archive links for when the articles were created in year / month format.

Created dates in database are stored in `YYYY-MM-DD` format and have written this so far.

```
$archive =
  mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT DateCreated FROM blog ORDER by DateCreated")
  or die("Could not execute query");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($archive) ){ 
  $Date = explode("-", $row["DateCreated"]);
  $Year = $Date[0];
  $Month = $Date[1];

  // Months of the year.
  $MonthName = array(
    "01" => "JAN",
    "02" => "FEB", 
    "03" => "MAR",
    "04" => "APR",
    "05" => "MAY",
    "06" => "JUN",
    "07" => "JUL",
    "08" => "AUG",
    "09" => "SEP",
    "10" => "OCT",
    "11" => "NOV",
    "12" => "DEC");    

 $archiveData .=
   "<a href='archive.php?".$Year."-".$Month.
   "'>".$MonthName[$Month]."-".$Year."</a><br />"; 
}
```

If I have these dates stored in my database

```
2012-04-07, 
2012-05-02, 
2012-05-13, 
2012-02-22,
```

Then the above code produces links as

```
FEB-2012, 
APR-2012, 
MAY-2012, 
MAY-2012,
```

It shows the months that have already been added, what I need to do is limit it to show it only once.

I think I need to change the query but not sure how to get the result I require any help would be appreciated.

Comment: w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  YEAR(DateCreated) AS yyyy,
  MONTH(DateCreated) AS mm
FROM blog 
ORDER BY DateCreated
```

and accordingly

```
$Year = $row["yyyy"];
$Month  = $row["mm"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you try to select

```
DATE_FORMAT(DateCreated , '%m/%Y')
```

instead of "DateCreated" ? Not sure of the result, but as far as I remember this should solve your problem.

Regards

Comment: Hi Seb i tried this method but was un-successful thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this query will be perfect for you - it selects first 3 month's letters and year of timestamp.

```
SELECT 
   substr(MONTHNAME(DateCreated), 1, 3) as month, 
   YEAR(DateCreated) as year
FROM blog 
ORDER by DateCreated DESC
```

**Edit:**
After several tests, i made perfect query for you - it returns date in `JAN-2012` format, so there is no need to format date in PHP. Here it is:

```
SELECT 
   CONCAT( UPPER(substr(monthname(DateCreated), 1 ,3)), '-', YEAR(DateCreated)) as date
FROM blog 
ORDER by DateCreated DESC
```

Comment: Is there any mysql error? I tried it and it worked perfectly for me

Comment: How did you pass it to the link as $row[DateCreated]

Comment: If you want to pass it exactly as `$row[DateCreated]`, you need to select query `AS DateCreated`. It should work

Answer (score 0):

My final result was this.

```
$archive = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(DateCreated) AS YYYY, MONTH(DateCreated) AS MM FROM blog ORDER BY DateCreated") or die("Could not execute query");

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($archive) ){

                $Year               = $row["YYYY"];
                $Month              = sprintf("%02s",$row["MM"]);

                // Months of the year.
                $MonthName = array(
                                    "01" => "JAN",
                                    "02" => "FEB", 
                                    "03" => "MAR",
                                    "04" => "APR",
                                    "05" => "MAY",
                                    "06" => "JUN",
                                    "07" => "JUL",
                                    "08" => "AUG",
                                    "09" => "SEP",
                                    "10" => "OCT",
                                    "11" => "NOV",
                                    "12" => "DEC"
                                );    

                    $archiveData .=   "<a href='archive.php?".$Year."-".$Month."'>".$MonthName[$Month]."-".$Year."</a><br />"; 
                }
```

Comment: Did you tried my method? You won't need any date formatting in PHP and arrays like `$MonthName`

Comment: Now trying your method will reply with results, thanks for post.